# how print unsigned integer time in human readable form?

Tags: c, integer, unsigned, localtime

I have a rawtime unsigned integer and I try to print it in some human readable form

```
uint32_t rawtime=3675431915;
struct tm * timeinfo;
timeinfo = localtime ((const time_t *) &rawtime);
asctime(timeinfo);
printf ("Time and date: %s", asctime(timeinfo));
```

it crashes when I call asctime(timeinfo). Can anybody show me how to do it properly? The problem is I didn't see any example how to do this with unsigned integer or integer. This http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/ shows example only with time_t but from the example it's not clear how to use uint32_t .

Note: there is also warning: this decimal constant (3675431915) is unsigned only in ISO C90

Comment: Where exactly do you get that *raw* time value from? Because from the simple integer value there is no way to determine the interpretation of that value without additional information.

Comment: I run the code as it is (including time.h). In later use the value will be read from file and it must be uint32_t

Comment: https://ideone.com/X3I1F5 no problem at all. try to check if there is a bug in your libc or cc.

Comment: try `uint32_t rawtime=3675431915ul;`

Comment: @Degustaf still the same problem. BTW: I have timeinfo NULL pointer ...

Comment: @user1141649 Okay.  Sounds like `localtime` fails. try adding `time_t rawtime_t = (time_t) rawtime;` followed by `timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime_t);`  See if `rawtime_t` is what you expect.

Comment: You can also check `errno` if `timeinfo` is NULL.  That will give you an error number (that can be translated to an error message) to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Are you sure 3675431915 is the correct value? Assuming the typical `time_t` representation as the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, that would be Thu 2086-06-20 17:18:35 UTC.

Comment: @Degustaf I did as you say: rawtime_t is -619535381 and timeinfo is still null. I call `strerror(errno)` just after localtime and it is No error. The number in HEX is `0xEBA3 12DB` . Maybe the date is encoded in some special way. I will reread documentation: There is  
EF 82 DF E2 at offset 0x08 Low = 3806298863 and  

E8 C7 C6 01 at offset 0x0C High = 29804520
=> February 27, 2007 I think I must to convert the numbers using some special method. I didn't be aware of it before.

Answer (score 2):

Simply said as is, since `sizeof(time_t)` is not defined (it is usually either `4` or `8`), there is no portable way to convert a `uint32_t` into a `time_t`.

One reason --for example-- is that on a 32-bit machine `time_t` cannot even hold the timestamp you are providing in your example.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uint32_t rawtime = 3675431915u;

    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time_t t = rawtime;
    // note absence of indirect convert via pointer
    // I have no idea, why you wanted to do this, anyway
    timeinfo = localtime (&t);
    asctime(timeinfo);
    printf ("Time and date: %s", asctime(timeinfo));
    return 0;
}
```

will yield `Time and date: Thu Jun 20 19:18:35 2086` on machine with 64-bit `time_t`, but yield `Time and date: Mon May 15 11:50:19 1950` on a 32-bit machine. This is because of the range overflow, when converting `rawtime` into the signed integer that is `time_t`.

Conversion only works under the assumption that `time_t` is a signed integer on all target platforms (no guarantees). And even in this case, you should guard against overflowing values.

Comment: 1) C does not specify that `uint32_t` and `time_t` are the same size as you said.  They could even differ per FP and integers. 2) Suggest `struct tm  timeinfo; timeinfo = *localtime (&t); ...  asctime(&timeinfo);` as the value returned from `localtime()` points to a static place that other time functions may overwrite. This would apply if my `...` included other time functions.

Comment: Where did I imply that `uint32_t` and `time_t` are the same size?

Comment: Additional comment: If you want thread safety and similar, use `localtime_r()`. That's what it's for ...

Comment: `localtime()` is part of the standard library.  `localtime_r()` is not  (C99,C11) and so may not exist.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
/* localtime example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* puts, printf */
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, time, localtime */
#include <stdint.h>  /* This header is part of the type support library, providing fixed width integer types. */

int main() {
    uint32_t rawtime=3675431915;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    timeinfo = localtime ((const time_t *) &rawtime);
    asctime(timeinfo);
    printf ("Time and date: %s", asctime(timeinfo));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I added header stdint.h (and all lines checked as you have it). It still crashes on the line with asctime ... The warning is still present: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90